# How to take user input for date of birth in DD MM YYYY format? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to build a signup screen in which user needs to input date of birth in DD MM YYYY format, something like the image below.

[image]

I'm creating a single enum for input textfields and the code looks like

```
struct Test: View {
    
    @StateObject var testViewModel: TestViewModel = .init()
    
    @FocusState var activeField: BirthdayFields?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                BirthdayField()
                    .padding()
                
                
                Button{Task {await testViewModel.letsDate()}}
                       label: {
                    Text("Birthday")
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background{
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                                .fill(.yellow)
                        }
                }
                .disabled(checkStates())
                .opacity(checkStates() ? 0.4 : 1)
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .onChange(of: testViewModel.dobFields) { newValue in
               DOBConditions(value: newValue)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func BirthdayField() -> some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 6) {
            
            ForEach(0..<8, id: \.self) { index in
                
                VStack {
                    
                    TextField("D", text: $testViewModel.dobFields[index])
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        .textContentType(.dateTime)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .focused($activeField, equals: activeStateForIndex(index: index))
                        .onAppear{
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                activeField = activeStateForIndex(index: index)
                            }
                        }
                    
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(activeField == activeStateForIndex(index: index) ? .blue : .gray.opacity(0.4))
                        .frame( height: 4)
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func checkStates() -> Bool {
        for index in 0..<8{
            if testViewModel.dobFields[index].isEmpty{return true}
        }
        return false
    }
    
    func activeStateForIndex(index: Int) -> BirthdayFields {
        switch index {
        case 0: return .field1
        case 1: return .field2
        case 2: return .field3
        case 3: return .field4
        case 4: return .field5
        case 5: return .field6
        case 6: return .field7
        default: return .field8
        }
    }
    
    enum BirthdayFields {
        case field1
        case field2
        case field3
        case field4
        case field5
        case field6
        case field7
        case field8
    }
    
    func DOBConditions(value: [String]) {
        
        for index in 0..<8{
            if value[index].count == 8{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    testViewModel.dobText = value[index]
                    testViewModel.dobFields[index] = ""
                }
                return
            }
        }
        
        // moving next field if current field type
        for index in 0..<7{
            if value[index].count == 1 && activeStateForIndex(index: index) == activeField {
                activeField = activeStateForIndex(index: index + 1)
            }
        }
        
        // moving back if current is empty and previous is not empty
        for index in 1...7{
            if value[index].isEmpty && !value[index - 1].isEmpty{
                activeField = activeStateForIndex(index: index - 1)
            }
        }
        
        // limiting only one text
        for index in 0..<8{
            if value[index].count > 1{
                testViewModel.dobFields[index] = String(value[index].last!)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The result looks like below image

[image]

My question is, how can I achieve the DD MM YYYY format? Should I create separate enums for date, month, and year? And how does moving to next field or deleting the previous ones work in that case?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be much simpler to have a single text field and validate it using a date formatter?

Comment: I know, right? And using a DatePicker would be even easier...but these are the requirements...so...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson actually if you go through any accessibility evaluation, that's what they usually don't recommend. They prefer you to have 3 fields: date, month, year, all separate. Having said that, I have never seen implementation or reason to have field per digit.

Comment: I would say that you don’t NEED to take the date in any particular format at all. You just need to ask the user for their date of birth. Use a DatePicker or something. You MIGHT need to send that date to a back end service with a particular format. But that has no relation on how the user needs to input it. If you have been given this design to implement, push back on it. It’s terrible. There is a reason native controls exist, they make the app far easier to use for everyone.

Comment: Agree. Refer the designer to the Apple HIG. If you use a date picker you not only get a control that the user is familiar with, but also you have to write much less code and get features such as accessibility and locale support "for free"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
struct DateOfBirthTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let placeholderText: String
    
    let placeholderAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.gray as Any
    ]
    
    let inputAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white as Any
    ]
    
    @Binding var input: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<DateOfBirthTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let placeholderSubstring = placeholderText[input.endIndex...]
        
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: String(placeholderSubstring),
            attributes: placeholderAttributes
        )
        
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 45, weight: .bold)
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.attributedText = attributedString
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<DateOfBirthTextField>) {
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        uiView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> DateOfBirthTextField.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: DateOfBirthTextField
        
        init(parent: DateOfBirthTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            setCursorPosition(for: textField)
        }
        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            let isDeleting: Bool = string == ""
            
            if isDeleting {
                if parent.input.count > 0 {
                    parent.input = parent.input[..<parent.input.index(before: parent.input.endIndex)].uppercased()
                }
            } else {
                let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
                let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
                guard
                    allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet),
                    parent.input.count < parent.placeholderText.count
                else { return false }
                
                parent.input += string
            }
            
            if parent.input.count <= parent.placeholderText.count {
                setCombinedText(for: textField, isDeleting: isDeleting)
                setCursorPosition(for: textField)
                return false
            }
            
            return true
        }
        
        func resetPlaceholder(for textField: UITextField) {
            parent.input = ""
            setCombinedText(for: textField)
        }
        
        fileprivate func setCursorPosition(for textField: UITextField) {
            guard let cursorPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: parent.input.count)
            else { return }
            
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: cursorPosition, to: cursorPosition)
        }
        
        fileprivate func setCombinedText(for textField: UITextField, isDeleting: Bool = false) {
            var placeholderSubstring = parent.placeholderText[parent.input.endIndex...]
            let isWhiteSpace = placeholderSubstring.first?.lowercased() == " "
            
            let space = isWhiteSpace ? " " : ""
            
            if !isDeleting {
                parent.input += space
                
                if parent.input.count > 0 && isWhiteSpace {
                    placeholderSubstring = placeholderSubstring.dropFirst()
                }
            }
            
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
                string: parent.input + placeholderSubstring,
                attributes: parent.placeholderAttributes
            )
            
            attributedString.addAttributes(
                parent.inputAttributes,
                range: NSMakeRange(0, parent.input.count)
            )
            
            
            textField.attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dateOfBirth = ""
    
    var body: some View {
       DateOfBirthTextField(placeholderText: "DD MM YYYY", input: $dateOfBirth) 
    }
}
```

Have fun!!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**